# Why storyboard constraints are changed automatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

Friends my project is in ending state ,but even in my backup all constraints are changed i,don't know how and why ,but if i run all is available but in storyboard can't see any thing.

it is storyboard image :

[image]

it is simulator image :

[image]

how i have to solve this ,i need my previous constraints how its changed automatically ?

Comment: if you have used size classes then check which size you have used in earliar.

Comment: no i didn't used size classes .

Comment: Can you correct your question please? It's not very easy to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No issues, you can get your storyboard clean and restored.

1. Goto your storyboard, select the particular view controller/ table view controller.
2. Choose the file inspector on the right side, goto **Interface Builder Document** section **uncheck** **Use Size Classes**
3. Proceed by choosing **Disable Size Classes** option from the dialog popup. Find that all your views have been visible now, and there is the possibility of constraint warnings.
4. Click on the yellow mark to the right side of your view controller, update the constraints one by one.
5. At the end, your previous viewcontroller/tableviewcontroller state is restored.

If you have more than one viewcontroller/tableviewcontroller has this problem, do the above steps for all.

Note: Don't forget to **check** the **Use Size Classes**  back.

Happy coding :)

Comment: thanks but my all view controllers are changed why ,and i was updated my xcode is it problem ?

Comment: Well it's a pretty lengthy  info to write here in comment, read here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html, Previously use size classes selected by default, If our viewControler changed to Any size classes, then all your views will be hidden, In order to bring it back to the used size class, toggling the check will restore the views.